# javascript difference between function constructor object and an object inside object

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to comprehend/understand GraphQL schema instructor have used.

So first he did something like this

```
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({  
    name: 'Book', 

    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLString},
        name: { type: GraphQLString},
        genre: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
})
```

Here, he mentioned that reason *fields needs to be a function is because later when we have multiple type and they have reference to one another. then unless we wrap it in function, one type won't know what other types (more later)*

And afterwards when he was making **RootQuery** he did something like this

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "RootQueryType",
    fields: {
        book: {
          type: BookType, 
          args: { id: { type: GraphQLString }},
          resolve(parent, args){
           args.id
            }
         }
      }
})
```

Here, he did   `fields: {` instead of  `fields: () => ({` for which he gave following reason

*We don't need to wrap it like the field above because we don't need to worry about the order so much inside root Query*

**[Question:]** I am unable to understand his explanation so I was looking for someone to explain me why he did `fields: {` instead of  `fields: () => ({` this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because inside your RootQueryType, the field book does not contain any reference of any of your custom declared types let's say AuthorType. Your field book is therefore, only dependant on either BookType or any of the other GraphQLObjects that you may have imported at the top. Same goes for the field author. There should not be any reference of BookType inside it.

However, in the case of your custom Types( BookType or AuthorType), they might contain references of each other and hence they are dependant on each other.

Therefore when defining those custom types, your fields needs to be wrapped inside function. But that's not a necessity when it comes to the  RootQuery.

If you want to know more about it. Look up the concept of Hoisting.

Comment: Hey @Haris, Firstly thanks a lot for your answer. I got what you are saying through author explanation as well. I am more interested to know the difference in execution when we use  `fields: {` instead of  `fields: () => ({` like how both of them differ and how do they execute.

Comment: First is an object, while the second one is a function that returns an object.

Comment: This might probably be stupid to ask but when shall we use object (nested inside object) and when shall we use function returning object? Can you please include this in length in your answer?

Comment: I believe when you use functions, they get hoisted to the top. So no dependency related issues happen. However, when you use objects/variables they are executed line by line. So if you are at line 5 and your object/variable is dependant on something you declared ahead in the program let's say like 10, it will cause an error. This does not happen in the case of functions.

Comment: Went through it later in the video and it makes sense now (although vaguely). Thanks a lot, Can you please include your last comment in the answer. (Marking this as answered)